# How to remove attribute from MongoDb Object?

Tags: mongodb

I have added MiddleName attribute to my Customer object. Customer is a simple Object() instance. I want to remove this attribute from my object. How can I do that? I am using MongoDb interactive Console.

Comment: Found the answer => delete customer.MiddleName

Answer (score 60):

You should use the $unset modifier while updating:

**To delete: (most recent syntax)**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    { 
        $unset : { 
            "properties.service" : 1 
        } 
    },
    {
        multi: true
    }
);
```

Updated thanks to **Xavier Guihot** comment!

**To delete: (only left for reference of the old syntax)**

// db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )

```
db.collection.update( 
    { 
        "properties.service" : { 
             $exists : true 
         } 
    }, 
    { 
         $unset : { 
             "properties.service" : 1 
         } 
    }, 
    false, 
    true
);
```

**To verify they have been deleted you can use:**

```
db.collection.find( 
    { 
        "properties.service" : { 
            $exists : true
         } 
    } 
).count(true);
```

Remember to use the multi option as true if you want to update multiple records.
In my case I wanted to delete the properties.service attribute from all records on this collection.

Comment: i have run this command on a db of 20million records. Its been 14 minutes already. Deleting one field.

Comment: Yep, I'm not surprised. Can you suggest a better way for a database designed to be schema-free?

Comment: The argument signature for db.collection.update was change in 2.2 : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Note that checking if the field exist is not necessary: `db.collection.update({}, { $unset: { "properties.service": 1 } }, { multi: true })`